# Setting the font style in WebView html issue

Tags: android, html, webview

I need to use the UhmanicHafs.ttf font in webView Html page to get the Expected output.

I am setting `uthmanic font`:

```
 webviewHTML.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/fonts/UthmanicHafs.ttf",
 myHtmlString, "text/html", Xml.Encoding.UTF_8.toString(), null);
```

Then I am getting the [Actual Output](http://postimg.org/image/sxji56ww3/)

If I removed the `UthmanicHafs.ttf` font like this :

```
  webviewHTML.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", myHtmlString, "text/html", Xml.Encoding.UTF_8.toString(), null);
```

I am getting this [Expected Output](http://postimg.org/image/livdci9bn/)

***What I need:***

I need to use the Uthmanic Font and get the Expected output.Anyone can help with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need set the custom font like below in your css  file

For this example wrote the CSS to:

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'feast';
   src: url('fonts/yourfont.ttf');
 }

 body {font-family: 'feast';}


Then use the assets path as the base url:

    loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",myhtml,"text/html","utf-8",null);
```

then it should be working fine.